# Tumblr API v2 Fails to Upload Valid Photo

Tags: api, tumblr

Using the `blog/{blog-host}/post` API call in the v2 oAuth API in order to post a photo, I have a problem with specifying the "source" for the image. The API dictates that this parameter should be the source to an image:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting

I am using an image on my server, such as this one. The Facebook and other APIs accept and process it correctly:
http://streamified.me/p/d4xh6o/

Unfortunately, I get the following response from Tumblr:

> meta =         {
>
> ```
>        msg = "Bad Request";
>         status = 400;
> };
> response =         {
>     errors =             (
>         "Error uploading photo."
>     );
> ```
>
> };

Posting other status types works fine...

Comment: Could you please post some of the code that you used to get this to work? I'm having a hard time building my Post request.

Comment: Per my answer below, basically you just want to do a header('location: $image_url'); and then abort your script. If you don't have an $image_url (because it is local file data on your server), then just write the data to a temp  file and use that as the URL.

Comment: no, i mean like a full chunk of code... i think i'm just not clearly understanding how a post request needs to be laid out, and I cant seem to find good examples anywhere. This is exactly what i am wanting to do, i just cant seem to figure it out at all.

Comment: there's really no more code I could possibly provide. I mean, seriously, this is it: header('location: '.$image_url); return; ... once you've done that, your script redirects to the $image_url and aborts. That's it. You need an image url to redirect to of course, but I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it looks like I solved the problem. My server was serving the image (the above URL) via a PHP script. Even though the header data etc. was properly sent and the image showed fine in all browsers, the Tumblr API was not recognizing it as an image. Redirecting to a .jpg URL worked fine.

I'd consider this to be a bug in the Tumblr API, but the workaround is "good enough" for me.

Comment: the tumblr api is really really buggy. -_-

Comment: redirecting to a jpg url? do you mean you posted an image using the source parameter instead of data?

Comment: @ggwarpig Yes. If you look on the Tumblr API documentation it says it wants the data source as a string or URL but not as the actual data file which seems stupid....

Comment: Thank you, Sir! You've just saved my day! I've been struggling uploading image for Photo Post in all possible ways (data/data64/source url) and I've been receiving Bad Request all the time. Your JPG answer gave me an idea - I've tried another file and it turned out Tumblr just had some trouble with that exact gif I'm trying to upload!! Sometimes It's not the code, it's the resource you're uploading being wrong :D